# Javascript dies when a div with getElementsByClassName is not found. How can I improve this?

Tags: javascript, liquid, shopify-app

I am writing a script for a Shopify theme app extension intended to look for a specific div on the page and replace it with my content. However, with all the various themes available on Shopify, the way developers label this div is not consistent. I would like to compile every possible combination and have it ready in the app to find this particular div and inject my content. I started simply with this...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('my__div')[0].innerHTML = 'new content';
document.getElementsByClassName('my--div')[0].innerHTML = 'new content';
```

When testing, any theme with 'my__div' worked. Any theme with 'my--div' did not.

I flip-flopped the lines of the code and saw that I got the reverse effect.

What causes the second line to fail when the first line cannot be executed? And is there an if statement I can use to make it work for all scenarios?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `.my__div` a child of `.my--div` (and vice versa)?

Comment: A simple way would be to query the elements using `querySelectorAll`, and then iterate through the returned NodeList. If the list is empty, no iteration is executed, nor any error will break the code.

Comment: esqew, no, they would not exist on the same page.

Comment: thanks, Teemu, I will look into that more

Comment: Teemu, that seemed to do the trick! Thank you for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

Teemu directed me to this solution. I thought I would post the working code to help future visitors...

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".my--div, .my__div");
var i;
for (i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = 'new content';
}
```

Now I can add variation I find into the first line and it will still work on any theme the app loads onto.

Cheers!